# Tikz for loop for nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I construct a for loop so that I get

```
\draw [step=0.5cm, gray!80] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw [orange] plot [only marks, mark size=2.5, mark=*] coordinates {(0,0) (4,4)};
```

at every intersection?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill My mistake. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `\foreach` loop, with a step size of `0.5`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [step=0.5cm, gray!80] (0,0) grid (4,4);
    \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,4} {%
        \foreach \y in {0,0.5,...,4} {%
            \draw [orange] plot [only marks, mark size=2.5, mark=*] 
                coordinates {(\x,\y)};
        }%
    }%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```